# Creating a charge from Android client to server for Stripe

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am having a difficult time doing an HTTP-POST from my Android application to my server in order to make a Stripe charge.

My Stripe server works fine on its own after I followed the [tutorial found on the Stripe website](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails). My working application [can be found here](https://agile-chamber-46872.herokuapp.com/charges/new).

Just as an insight, my Charges controller looks like:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
    protect_from_forgery
    def new
    end

    def create
      # Amount in cents
      @amount = 500

      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => params[:stripeEmail],
        :source  => params[:stripeToken]
      )

      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer    => customer.id,
        :amount      => @amount,
        :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
        :currency    => 'usd'
      )

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to new_charge_path
    end
end
```

I am trying to pass my token to my server in order to create a charge. However, it is resulting in the following error:

```
E/Volley: [714] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for https://agile-chamber-46872.herokuapp.com/charges/create?stripeToken=tok_*************&stripeEmail=xxxxxxxx@gmail.com
```

This is my android code where I am trying to do an HTTP POST to my server:

package com.snapwebdevelopment.scanhappy;

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.stripe.android.*;


import com.braintreepayments.cardform.view.CardForm;
import com.stripe.android.exception.AuthenticationException;
import com.stripe.android.model.Card;
import com.stripe.android.model.Token;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.android.volley.Response;

import static java.security.AccessController.getContext;

public class CreditCardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CardForm cardForm;
    private Button makePaymentButton;
    private Stripe stripe;
    private HashMap<String, Object> chargeInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_credit_card);

        makePaymentButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.makePaymentButton);

        cardForm = (CardForm) findViewById(R.id.card_form);
        cardForm.cardRequired(true)
                .expirationRequired(true)
                .cvvRequired(true)
                .postalCodeRequired(true)
                .mobileNumberRequired(true)
                .mobileNumberExplanation("SMS is required on this number")
                .actionLabel("Purchase")
                .setup(this);

        makePaymentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                validateCard();
            }
        });

    }

    private void validateCard(){


        chargeInfo = new HashMap<>();

        Card card = new Card(
                cardForm.getCardNumber(),
                Integer.valueOf(cardForm.getExpirationMonth()),
                Integer.valueOf(cardForm.getExpirationYear()),
                cardForm.getCvv()
        );

        card.validateNumber();
        card.validateCVC();

        stripe = null;
        try {
            stripe = new Stripe("pk_test_*************");
            stripe.createToken(
                    card,
                    new TokenCallback() {
                        public void onSuccess(Token token) {
                            // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
                            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(CreditCardActivity.this);
                            String url = "https://agile-chamber-46872.herokuapp.com/charges/create?stripeToken=" + token.getId() + "&stripeEmail=rebeccasheeler@gmail.com";

                            // Request a string response from the provided URL.
                            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                                            // your response
                                            Log.d("HTTP-RESPONSE", response);
                                        }
                                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    // error
                                }
                            }){
                                @Override
                                public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                                    String your_string_json = ""; // put your json
                                    return your_string_json.getBytes();
                                }
                            };
                            // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
                            queue.add(stringRequest);



                        }
                        public void onError(Exception error) {
                            // Show localized error message
                            Toast.makeText(CreditCardActivity.this, error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
            );
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void chargeUser() {

    }
}
```

I know I'm royally screwing up somewhere. What do I need to change in my Android code in order to properly POST to my server's REST api at `/create`?

Comment: @Selvin Correct me if I'm wrong, but `getBody()` is a method from Volley.Request that is meant to parse the response from the server. I don't think this would explain the 404 response I'm getting. Right now I just want to make sure I'm correctly posting to the server before parsing the response.

Comment: You are wrong, Request is not parsing ... It sends, well, body....

Comment: Volley is saying that when it attempts to hit that URL its getting a 404 - which is what Rails is returning. So you must not be hitting the correct path to your charges controller endpoint

Comment: You're also going to want to skip forgery protection for that endpoint - Android wont be sending back the authenticity token the way a Rails-generated form would. You'll want to use `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token`

Comment: @CodyCaughlan that's kind of what i thought (not using the right url). I will definitely try that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things:

- Firstly, for API endpoints like this one that your Android app is hitting you will need to disable the Rails form authenticity checking. Look into `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token`
- Volley is getting a HTTP 404 from your Rails app, so it's really nothing to do with your Android app per se; you are hitting the wrong URL/Path to your API endpoint
- By default, Rails will automatically call the `create` action on a controller when it receives an HTTP POST - thus, I am going to guess you really just want to perform an HTTP POST against

`https://agile-chamber-46872.herokuapp.com/charges`

And Rails will route that internally to the `create` action - you don't need to explicitly specify this in your Android HTTP request.

I believe it's this later point which is the true source of your HTTP 404

Hitting your API via curl:

```
$ curl -XPOST "https://agile-chamber-46872.herokuapp.com/charges?stripeToken=tok_abc&stripeEmail=foo@gmail.com"
```

Results in an HTTP 500 - which is not a 404, so we're getting somewhere. Check your Rail logs for the source of the error. Consider enabling a log collecting Heroku add-on like Papertrail

Comment: This was exactly it! I was able to get the HTML for the Charges#create view. I'm going to keep hammering in to see if I can get the response that I'm getting from Stripe, but this was immensely helpful. Thank you!